# Gauss vs Gauss' vs Gauss's?

Tags: grammar, scientific-language

Which of the three should be used? Gauss law vs Gauss' law vs Gauss's law? The middle one seems most correct but does that make the others incorrect? Or is it a matter of preference. Also, how do the three differ in pronounciation?

Comment: Syntactically speaking, both the possessive apostrophe ***and*** the possessive "s" itself should be present. We always drop that final "s" after a noun that ends with *two consecutive* "s" sounds such as **Jesus** or **Moses** (in both speech *and* writing). But we usually include it after nouns ending in a single "s" (so it's *I like **Gus's** car*, not *I like Gus car*).

Comment: But see [this usage chart.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Gauss+law%2CGauss%27+law%2CGauss%27s+law&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CGauss%20law%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CGauss%20%27%20law%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CGauss%20%27s%20law%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CGauss%20law%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CGauss%20'%20law%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CGauss%20's%20law%3B%2Cc0) ***Gauss's law*** is the most common orthography, but both the other forms do occur. The basic principle is ***Write the possessive letter "s" IF you pronounce it, not otherwise***.

Comment: It's usually as FF says, Gauss's law: like "Keats's poems". But as [Lynne Truss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eats,_Shoots_%26_Leaves) said, the rules are a matter of style and preference and are not set in stone.

Comment: @Old Brixtonian Some wag named their pub "The Misplaced Apostrophe's ".

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth. Love it :-) Living where I do, yet supporting NUFC, I regularly visit both _St Thomas' Hospital_ and _St. James' Park_: their official names, as Truss pointed out.